How to create a PythonMmac app using Pyinstaller?
I created an app using Py2App for Mac. The app works fine through the terminal, but not through the double click. So now I am trying to use PyInstaller after reading some of the questions here.
I am using a shared cloud MacOS with Sonoma 14.3.
Installation:
Install python3.11
JupyterLab/VS Code/Text editor - I am using Sublime on Mac
Pip3 install hl7
$ pip3 install -U py2app 

Setup:

Create a python file with required code for the project. (Eg: TestLaunch09.py)

Create a new file setup.py in the folder where the TestLaunch09.py resides.
In the setup.py enter the following and save the file:


from setuptools import setup
APP = ['TestLaunch09.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {
}
setup(
    app = APP,
    data_files = DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app':OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app','hl7'],
)


At the terminal, to create the clickable app for Mac:

$ python setup.py py2app

This successfully creates a new dist folder.
Inside the dist there is an icon for App with the name ‘TestLaunch09’. The app can be executed at the terminal, but clicking on the icon does not work. This command executes the app through the terminal:
$ TestLaunch09.app/Contents/MacOS/TestLaunch09

But double-clicking shows the following error in a pop-up window:
Launch error
See the py2app website for debugging launch issues

I have tried the following, without success:

Added exception handling to the code.
Tried iterations of the code.
Added a log file to see if the error is captured.

Is there an issue with Py2App? I am expecting the double click of the app to work.

Sorry I missed to mention. I tried Py2app and since the app wouldn't open through the click, then I started looking up PyInstaller.

py2app and pyinstaller are separate tools that are mutually exclusive. You can create an app bundles using pyinstaller alone. If you want to use PyInstaller, remove py2app from your project first.
By default, PyInstaller will simply create an executable file (for example, a CLI application you can call from your terminal). To create an app bundle that can be launched as a normal MacOS app, pass the --windowed argument.
pyinstaller --onedir --windowed myscript.py

See Building macOS App Bundles for more information.
